# How to properly setup model, POCO class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, data-annotations, poco

I'm slightly confused on how to properly setup my model. Below you'll see my POCOs and I'm wondering how I can auto increment the ID's and if it's necessary to set the data annotation [Key]. Is there a naming convention of some sort which makes EF recognize the ID/primary key or do I have to use the [Key] data annotation?

Also is it necessary to set a [Key] data annotation in the child entity?

```
    public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime Reg { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Stats> Stats { get; set; } 
}

public class Stats
{
    [Key]
    public int StatId { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public string Height { get; set; }
    public string Weight { get; set; }
    public bool Sex { get; set; }
}

public class BodylogContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Stats> Stats { get; set; } 

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<BodylogContext>(null);
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just getting with MVC too and I found that [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) tutorial answered most of the questions you have asked.

By default, the Entity Framework interprets a property that's named ID or classnameID as the primary key.  So in your `User` class, you do not need the [Key] attribute on the UserId property.  In your `Stats` class, the property does not match the name of the class (you have pluralised the name) so here you would need the attribute.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 1):

You should look up Entity Framework Code First tutorials for more details.

Specifically, in your case and a few basic rules (disclaimer:) **I'm not trying to cover everything** just a few basic ones....

- You can remove `[Key]` -
  if you use `<Entity>Id` - or just `Id` it's made into a PK by default.
  Same goes for 'FK-s' and related `navigation properties` (except that `<Property>Id` is also mapped by convention),
  It's case insensitive.
- Identity is by default - for pk types that makes sense - int, long... - not for strings,
- If you have `more than one` pk - then you'd need to 'decorate' it with Key - or in fluent config,

etc...

**Note:** you can adjust and remove `conventions` from the fluent configuration.
Also from EF6 you'll be able to define a new ones for your code.

> **My recommendation**: Turn on `Migrations` and look up the migrations
>   script code (.cs file) generated file. It always has the clear
>   description of what are keys, indexes etc. Best way to learn how your
>   Db is actually created.

Comment: Thank you I found this really helpful, appreciate your answer.